# Backup restore IIS 6.0 settings across machines

Tags: iis-6

I have two machines and I want to transfer the all the websites on one machine to the other
Basically clone the IIS piece as it were
A few points
1) Both machines are Win 2033 and IIS 6.0
2) The two machines are not on the same domain, cant see each other. I have a machine set up with one hosting provider. I am moving hosting providers, so I want to quickly duplicate the setup
3)I have all the vdir set up exactly the same way on disk by just copying the files over so that should not be an issue
4) I tried the iisback.vbs but that seems to be including machine specific information as per the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDeploy is Microsoft's new tool for this which will help with transferring of sites between servers.

Or, if you use iisback.vbs or iiscnfg.vbs, make sure to set the password (even though its optional).  That will encrypt the credentials and allow them to work on the other servers as long as the username/password exists there (or better yet, if you're using domain accounts).

It's a bit lengthy but this article covers the iiscnfg method: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2006/06/07/IISCnfg.vbs---IIS-Settings-Replication.aspx.

Comment: if I understand this correctly what youre saying is there should be a username password combination on both machines such that they are identical?
thanks

Comment: Yes and no.  That is essential (unless you don't mind manually resetting all users after the migration), but in addition to that make sure that when you use iisback or iiscnfg that you set the password.  If you don't, it can only be restored to the same server.

My recommendation is to look at MSDeploy though.  It was just released (RTW) 2 weeks ago and is Microsoft's new solution for copying sites between servers.  It's probably going to be an easier solution for you.

Comment: worked with the password thing I'll definitely look at deploy
thanks